# How to make tests with find and date conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, tdd

I'm trying to develop some tests for a method which is responsible for retrieve some users created after some date. I don't know how to mock tests for it. The method is the following:

```
def user_list
  render :nothing => true, :status => 422 if params[:time_param].blank?

  time = Time.parse(params[:time_param])
  @users = User.find(:all, :select => 'id, login, email',
                           :conditions => ["created_at > ?", time])
  render :json => { :users => @users }
end
```

end

This is my spec:

```
describe UsersController do
  context "when receiving time parameter" do
    before (:each) do
      @time_param = "2013-01-25 00:01:00"
      user1 = mock_model(User, :created_at => Time.parse('2013-01-25 00:00:00'))
      user2 = mock_model(User, :created_at => Time.parse('2013-01-25 00:01:00'))
      user3 = mock_model(User, :created_at => Time.parse('2013-01-25 00:02:00'))

      @users = []
      @users << user1 << user2 << user3
    end

    it "should retrieve crimes after 00:01:00 time" do
      User.stub(:find).with(:all, :select => 'id, login, email').and_return(@users)
      get :user_list, { :time_param => @time_param }
      JSON.parse(response.body)["users"].size.should eq 1
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that it always returns all users despite of returning just one. (the last one).  Where am I mistaking?

Help me =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not testing what you have to test there, on a controller spec you only need to test that the method that you want is called with the parameters that you want, in your case, you have to test that the User model receives :find with parameters :all, :select => 'id, login, email', :conditions => ["created_at > ?", time] (with time the value that should be there.

Also, that logic does not belong to the controller, you should have a class method on User, something like select_for_json(date) to wrap around that find method (you can find a better name for it)

Then your controller becomes:

```
def user_list
  render :nothing => true, :status => 422 if params[:time_param].blank?

  time = Time.parse(params[:time_param])
  @users = User.select_for_json(time)
  render :json => { :users => @users }
end
```

your spec would be

```
before(:each) do
  @users = mock(:users)
  @time_param = "2013-01-25 00:01:00"
end

it "retrieve users for json" do
  User.should_receive(:select_for_json).once.with(@time).and_return(@users)
  get :user_list, { :time_param => @time }
  assigns(:users).should == @users
end
```

that way you are sure that your action does what it does and the spec is A LOT faster since you are not creating users

then you can test that method on the model specs, there you have to create some users, invoke that method and check the users returned (don't stub/mock anything on your model spec)

Comment: I tried to add 3 mock User in "@users", each one with different created_at time (2013-01-25, 2013-01-26, 2013-01-27), as I did in my post. Then, I set the @time_param to 2013-01-26 and replace once to twice at should_receive method. Why it retrieved 1 user instead of 2?

Comment: copy the code somewhere so I can see it, is your method called once or twice on your controller? if your controller only call the method once then don't put twice :P. You shouldn't care about the created_at of the users, the query will never be executed anyway because it's an expectation, not the real method, to test that the method does the correct query do a spec for the User model and then DON'T stub or mock any user, create them with the factory and do the query

Answer (score 0):

Your `stub` call is telling `find` to ignore what it thought it was supposed to do and return `@users` instead. It will not attempt to match the conditions.

Unfortunately, to do your test I think you're going to have to allow the `find` to execute through your database which means you can't use `mock_model`s. You probably will want to do either `User.create(...)` or `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` (or some other factory / fixture).

Of course doing it this way, you may hit `MassAssignment` issues if you use `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected`, but those are easy enough to `stub` out.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That's what I did to work around this problem. However, I don't like using FactoryGirl, I would like to know to fix this using just mocks.